# Installing and Loading Module

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I want my script to be able to discover if the user has a module installed and if it is not installed to perform the install and load the module. I have the commands to perform discovering the module, but not how to install it if it doesn't exist and load the module.

Any help would be appreciated! See the code below;

```bsh
if ((Get-Module | Select Name, Version | Where {$_.Name -like "*AzureRM*"}).Count -lt 1)
{
        Import-Module -Name AzureRM
}
```

Comment: Hello @Newbie77 and welcome. What have you tried so far to get the install piece working?

Comment: Hi, so far, I have not tried anything..any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for importing the new Azure Module:

```
# This script will not function without the Azure Modules
if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "Az*" -Verbose:$false)) {
    if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "Az" -Verbose:$false) {
        Uninstall-Az
    }
    Write-Output "Installing Azure modules"
    Install-Module -Name "Az" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose:$false | Out-Null
}
else {
    Write-Verbose "Azure PowerShell module already installed."
}
# Import required modules
$Modules = @("Az.Accounts", "Az.Resources", "Az.Storage")
$SaveVerbosePreference = $global:VerbosePreference
$global:VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
foreach ($Module in $Modules) {
    if (-not (Get-Module -Name $Module -Verbose:$false)) {
        Write-Output "Importing $Module module"
        Import-Module -Name $Module -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose:$false | Out-Null
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "$Module module already imported."
    }
}
$global:VerbosePreference = $SaveVerbosePreference
```

It will also work for the older modules. Also with Azure you can import just the components you require as per the above example.